# Powershell WMI: issue passing parameters to Win32_TSGatewayServer class methods

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm running into issues while trying to execute methods of the WMI Class `Win32_TSGatewayServer` using Powershell using the remote desktop gateway role on Server 2012 R2.

My goal is to export/import Remote Desktop Gateway configurations from one system to another. `Win32_TSGatewayServer` seems to include the required methods:

- [Export method of the Win32_TSGatewayServer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb892054(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Import method of the Win32_TSGatewayServer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb892059(v=vs.85).aspx)

I was able to get it to work to a certain extend but I am failing to pass the ExportType/ImportType parameters to the method call.

What I am currently using is:

```
$source = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\CIMV2\TerminalServices -Class Win32_TSGatewayServer -ComputerName rdg1
$destination = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\CIMV2\TerminalServices -Class Win32_TSGatewayServer -ComputerName rdg2
$settings = $source.Export(0).XmlString
$destination.Import(0,$settings,$null)
```

This seems to export/import the whole configuration.

How can I call the export/import specifying the ImportType parameter? No matter what I try, each time I specify a parameter different to `0` it fails

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $source.Export(1)
Exception calling "Export" : ""
At line:1 char:1
+ $source.Export(1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException
```

**Update 1**

Using Server 2012 R2. The aim is to completely mimic the behaviour of the export/import function in the GUI.

The answer of JamesQMurphy sheds more light on how the bitmap is to be handeled. As briefly mentioned in the comment I was able to use Export() with some parameters (e.g. 0, 32 and 33) but others that should work would fail (like 1, 3 and 5).

This lead me to the following idea:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -le 128; $i++) 
{
  $source.Export($i).XmlString | Out-File C:\temp\$i.txt
}
```

Which will generate a file for each call succeeded as it will throw exceptions otherwise. From the results it was apparent that 65 out of the 128 parameters generated valid exports:

- 0
- 32-63
- 96-127

Then I hashed all the files to see if their contents differ and the only files having the same hash are those with Export(0) and Export(127).

So the bitmaps seem to work at least partly, but with a different mapping(?) as described in the MSDN article (which was since I have posted the question and now reflects the int values instead of the bit table)

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` in the error message suggests that you actually have a collection of objects, not a single object.  You can confirm this by calling `$source.GetType()`;  if the type is actually `object[]`, then you have a collection:

```
$source = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\CIMV2\TerminalServices -Class Win32_TSGatewayServer -ComputerName rdg1
$source.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name          BaseType
-------- -------- ----          --------
True     True     Object[]      System.Array
```

If this is the case, and you know for a fact that you are interested in the *first* object, you can simply call `$source[0].Export(1).XmlString`.  Otherwise, you will need to loop over the collection with `ForEach-Object`.  Alternatively, you can pipe the results to `Select-Object -First 1`.

One other note:  The documentation for the `Import` and `Export` methods state that the values for `ImportType` are *bit values*.  This means that you need to pass the values in the **Actual Value** column.  You can also add values if you want a combination.

```
Bit Number    Actual Value     Meaning
----------    ------------     -------
    0               1          Export all RD CAPs
    1               2          Export a list of all Network Policy Server (NPS) servers.
    2               4          Export all RD RAPs.
    3               8          Export all resource groups.
    4              16          Export a list of all load-balancing servers.
    5              32          Export all RD Gateway-related server settings.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case $source.GetType() returns the actual object, not an array, so the methods can be called correctly. However I am unclear about the bitmask. While Export(0), Export(32) and Export(33) do return different values Export(1), 2, 5 return the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have RDS to test on, but those sounds like static methods. Try:

```
$source = Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace "root\CIMV2\TerminalServices" -Class "Win32_TSGatewayServer" -Name "Export" -ArgumentList 1 -ComputerName "rdg1"
$xml = $source | Select-Object -ExpandProperty XmlString
$destination = Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace "root\CIMV2\TerminalServices" -Class "Win32_TSGatewayServer" -Name "Import" -ArgumentList 1, $xml -ComputerName "rdg1"

#If you need a value for MergeOrReplace, try:
#$destination = Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace "root\CIMV2\TerminalServices" -Class "Win32_TSGatewayServer" -Name "Import" -ArgumentList 1, $xml, 0 -ComputerName "rdg1"
```

Comment: Doesnt work (just testet the first Invoke-Method): `Invoke-WmiMethod : Invalid method Parameter(s)
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace "root\CIMV2\TerminalServices" -Class "Win32_TSGatewa ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-WmiMethod], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWmiMethod`

Comment: What properties (except PSComputerName and __*) does this return `(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\CIMV2\TerminalServices -Class Win32_TSGatewayServer -List).GetMethodParameters("Export")` ?

Comment: I used your parameter value 0 for Export-/ImportType, which isn't a valid value. It's the 0-bit (value 1) that exports CAPs. Try updated answer. What policies do you need? You need to combine the values to select multiple types of policies to export. Ex. CAPs (1) + Radius servers (2) = 3

Comment: I was aware of that and tested with other values to, however your method does not work at all. Please see the update 1 of my question

Comment: Okay. Then I guess you need the object for this method. As for the export type I can't help you as I can't test it myself.